# Redirected you too many times

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I'm getting error "Redirected too many times" when I'm opening a PDF. Which is being used a VF page for showing PDF through IFrame on Aura bundle on Community Sites.

[image]

Comment: The page probably redirects back to itself, possibly indirectly with one or more steps in between. Check which URLs it redirects to for a clue to what's going on. Maybe your site's error page redirects to another page which has an error?